# Одно и тоже значение Math.random в переменной

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Начал изучать JavaScript и столкнулся с ошибкой в книге.
Вообщем создаю два массива:

```
var mass = ["I", "We",];
var mass2 = ["love", "hate", "not", "return"];
```

Далее пишу рандом для них:

```
var math = mass[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
var math2 = mass2[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
```

НО! если писать рандом в переменной, то как я понял, он один раз считает и записывает это число как значение переменной.
Далее складываю все:

```
var result = math + " " + math2;
```

Ии при каждом вводе result мне выдает одно и то же выражение вместо рандомных.
Но если в консоли каждый раз вводить так:

```
mass[Math.floor(Math.random() * mass.length)] + mass2[Math.floor(Math.random() * mass2.length)];
```

То все прекрасно работает.
Задавал вопрос на другом форуме и у человека код работает.Но у меня почему то нет. Подскажите как это сделать, чтобы работало через переменную.

Comment: никак, значение в переменной не меняется, пока ты его сам не поменяешь

Comment: В конверт в прозрачным окошком положена **случайная** карта. Смотрим в окошко - туз пик. Смотрим второй раз - что увидим?

Comment: Я проверил с переменными, значения не повторяются

Comment: @Эникейщик а вообще, даже на js можно написать, что бы при каждом "просмотре" значение переменной менялось. Без актуального кода в вопросе сложно что-то сказать.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, каким образом? Что ты тут имеешь ввиду под "просмотром"?

Comment: @Grundy В слово "просмотр" (*Смотрим в окошко - туз пик. Смотрим второй раз - что увидим?*) я вложил то же самое значение, что и Эникейщик в его примере.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы добиться похожей структуры, Можно сделать это через функиции.

```
var math = () => mass[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
var math2 = () => mass2[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];

var result = math() + " " + math2();
```

Answer (score 1):

Разовью мысль @ВиталийДячук и доведу ее до абсурдности.

Так делать не стоит, это из раздела "вредные советы".

```js
var mass = ["I", "We", ];
var mass2 = ["love", "hate", "not", "return"];

Object.defineProperty(window, 'math', {
  get: () =>
    mass[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)]
});
Object.defineProperty(window, 'math2', {
  get: () =>
    mass2[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]
});


var result = math + " " + math2;
console.log(result);
result = math + " " + math2;
console.log(result);
result = math + " " + math2;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: (+) это из раздела "вредные советы"

Comment: @StrangerintheQ добавлю в ответ :)

Comment: стоит добавить, что это только для глобальных переменных, в общем случае такое не сработает

Comment: @Grundy что значит *в общем случае такое не сработает*?

Comment: а, мне показалось переменная и свойство одинакового называются. В данном случае да, дублирование переменной в глобальную область - выход